# When I place this code in onCreate() my application always crashes. how can I remove the error?

Tags: java, android, file-handling, android-file

When I place this code in the `onCreate()` method, my application always crashes. please help.

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(dir, "Gest_val.csv");
    String val1 = new String();
    try {
        Scanner inputStream = new Scanner(file);
        while (inputStream.hasNext()) {
            String data = inputStream.next();
            if (data.equals("+")) {
                tvOrientation.setText("found +");
                Modify_val.add(Integer.parseInt(val1));
                val1 = null;
            } else {
                tvOrientation.setText("NO +");
                val1 = data;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Does file Gest_val.csv exists?

Comment: What IS the error? Check your logcat.

Comment: Yes this file is stored in SDcard
In other activities i am able to modify the contents of the file easily but in main activity it crashes @M.S.

Comment: Without knowing what the error is, we can only guess. Check the log, and post the error stacktrace.

Comment: @MikeBaranczak How can I check log?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html Also: Your code has an empty `catch` block, which is almost always a very bad idea. This means that if an exception occurs, you have no way of knowing what it is.

Comment: Also, without knowning the contents of the file it is hard to guess if the code is actually suitable to parse its contents. The default delimiter of `Scanner` is whitespace, so parsing a CSV-file  without further setup seems fishy to me. Also: Mind your variable names, a `Scanner` is no `InputStream`. My current guess is `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: have you set the permission to read-write external storage?
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />